# How to recover if I use 'git checkout'?

Tags: git

After I have commited, I enter `git checkout` by mistake, and the terminal shows `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/quoted_price' by 1 commit.`, the `quoted_price` is my branch name now. And I don't know how to recover..

And another question is what happened when I enter `git checkout`

Who could help me with it, please?

Comment: What branch do you want to be on now? `git status` will show you the current state of your working directory and `git log` will show you recent commits.

Comment: I want to be on the quoted_price branch. And the log shows the last commit and all past commits, but the why does status show `# On branch quoted_price # Your branch is ahead of 'origin/quoted_price' by 1 commit.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get current commit : `git rev-parse HEAD` gives the current SHA hash, `git branch` gives the current branch.

To go to previous state: `git checkout quoted_price`

Comment: Yeah, I'm on the right commit now. And when I use `git checkout quoted_price`, it shows `Already on 'quoted_price'Your branch is ahead of 'origin/quoted_price' by 1 commit.` , what does it mean? Will it effect my project?

Comment: It means that you have made one commit ahead from the origin remote repository, that is the remote repository is behind your local repository. It's only an informational message to see that remote isn't up to date, if you want it to be you have to `git push`